# How do I handle the "Invalid field size for datatype" when using bcp?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to get a database into Azure SQL Database using bcp, but first I'm trying to get it to load into a local database on my dev machine. I've only used bcp once before, years ago, so I'm a newbie at it. I scripted the original database, then created the same database on my machine, with all of the tables empty. Then I used bcp to export one of the tables into a native file. Next, from PowerShell I issued this command:

```
bcp CoreFramework.APP.ExampleTable IN .\ExampleTable.bcp -T -n
```

That resulted in the following error:

> Starting copy... SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error =
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for
>   datatype
>
> 0 rows copied. Network packet size (bytes): 4096 Clock Time (ms.)
>   Total     : 1

I suspect the problem is one of the columns in this table. The ExampleTable has several data types in it, as an example of using those data types. Here's the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [APP].[ExampleTable](
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ForeignID] [bigint] NULL,
[RequiredNvarchar] [nvarchar](120) NOT NULL,
[UniqueNvarchar] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
[TinyIntField] [tinyint] NULL,
[SmallIntField] [smallint] NULL,
[IntField] [int] NULL,
[BigIntField] [bigint] NULL,
[SmallMoneyField] [smallmoney] NULL,
[MoneyField] [money] NULL,
[RealField] [real] NULL,
[FloatField] [float] NULL,
[DecimalField] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[NumericField] [numeric](10, 2) NULL,
[BitField] [bit] NULL,
[DateField] [date] NULL,
[TimeField] [time](7) NULL,
[SmallDateTimeField] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[DateTimeField] [datetime] NULL,
[DateTime2Field] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[NcharField] [nchar](50) NULL,
[VarcharField] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CharField] [char](50) NULL,
[VarcharMaxField] [varchar](max) NULL,
[NvarcharMaxField] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[VarbinaryField] [varbinary](max) NULL,
[Created_By] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
[Created_On] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Updated_By] [varchar](25) NULL,
[Updated_On] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
[UniqueNvarchar] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My guess is the problem is with NvarcharMaxField and VarbinaryField. How do I use bcp to get this data into the table on my machine?

Comment: Would you try issuing the command from a Command Prompt?  You may in fact have some data type issues, but this could be a case of the bcp command being incorrect resulting in a misleading error message.  I believe Power Shell interprets the bcp command differently.

Comment: I just issued the same bcp command in a command prompt. Just to make sure I got it right I fully qualified the .bcp file. Unfortunately it failed with this error, "Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid field size for datatype"

Comment: FWIW, I tried another importing another table in PowerShell, that doesn't have a NVARCHAR(MAX) or VARBINARY(MAX). That worked fine.

Comment: Have you been able to view the output file created from the source database table?  How does it look?  Are all the columns still formatted/aligned properly at the end of the file?

Comment: No Mark, I cannot read it when I open it in Notepad++. It is a binary file. That's likely because I extracted it in native format. Was that wrong?